# Which function is faster in terms of time complexity/space python

Tags: python, big-o

Suppose we could access yesterday's stock prices as a list, where:

The indices are the time in minutes past trade opening time, which was 9:30am local time.
The values are the price in dollars of Apple stock at that time.
So if the stock cost $500 at 10:30am, stock_prices_yesterday[60] = 500.

Write an efficient function that takes stock_prices_yesterday and returns the best profit I could have made from 1 purchase and 1 sale of 1 Apple stock yesterday.

The solution I came up with:

```
def get_best_stock_price(list):
    first_minimum_value = min(list)
    index_of_the_minimum_value = list.index(first_lowest_value)
    new_list_excluding_all_the_unwanted_items = list[new_list_index:]
    max_new = max(new_list)
    return max_new - first_minimum_value
```

The solution they offered:

```
def get_max_profit(stock_prices_yesterday):
  if len(stock_prices_yesterday) < 2:
      raise ValueError('Getting a profit requires at least 2 prices')
  min_price  = stock_prices_yesterday[0]
  max_profit = stock_prices_yesterday[1] - stock_prices_yesterday[0]
  for current_time in xrange(1, len(stock_prices_yesterday)):
      current_price = stock_prices_yesterday[current_time]
      potential_profit = current_price - min_price
      max_profit = max(max_profit, potential_profit)
      min_price  = min(min_price, current_price)

  return max_profit
```

Is my answer suffice in terms of what they offer? if not how can I improve it. And what is my function lacking?

The function they offer includes O(n) time and O(1)O(1) space in the language of Big O notation.

Comment: I'm not even sure your solution is correct. But anyway, it is O(N) time, and O(N) space. But again, more importantly, I don't think it is correct.

Comment: So, consider a list like this: `[1, 10, -1, 0]` You would get `-1` as min, and `0` as the max... but clearly, the most profit would be if you bought at `1` and sold at `10`...

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Ahhhhh, I was missing that point.

Comment: I *think* that unless you can put some constraints on your input, their approach has the best time/space complexity possible here: O(N) time and O(1) space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, your solution is wrong, but we'll get into why later.

Technically your solution is O(n), but not in a good way.

Calling `min` and `max` separately cost ~`n` operations each. Finding the index of an item cost another ~`n` operations. Your run time is really `3n` so technically bound by `n` but it could be much more efficient if you found all three things in a single for loop. Ex:

```
idx = 0
max = 0
min = 9999999
for i, item in enumerate(list):
    if item > max:
        max = item
    if item < min:
        min = item
        idx = i
```

Next, I'm not sure what `new_list_index` or `new_list` are in your program, but unless the list is sorted (which would make this entire problem trivial) you will need to search the entire list to find the maximum value.

Finally, because you are storing a slice of the input list with `new_list_excluding_all_the_unwanted_items` your space complexity is bound by the size of the input list, giving you a space complexity of O(n) as well.

Their method however uses a single for loop and uses only a fixed number of variables giving them O(n) time and O(1) space complexity.

As for improvement, I believe I can do **even better** than either solution.

```
def get_max_profit(list):
    """Use list[0] to store min
        and list[1] to store max
    """
    # Swap the first two if they are out of order
    if list[0] > list[1]:
        list[0], list[1] = list[1], list[0]
    # Find min and max in remainder of list
    for price in list[2:]:
        if price < list[0]:
            list[0] = price
        if price > list[1]:
            list[1] = price
     # Return the difference
     return list[1] - list[0]
```

My solution works by using `list[0]` to store the `min` value and `list[1]` to store the `max` value. My solution is still O(n) time and O(1) space but is **completely in place** and does not require any additional storage.

It also sacrifices readability for a negligible performance gain and so should never be used.